# Windows 10 GRASS init error on QGIS 3.10.4 install

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-3

I am a noob who is trying to reinstall QGIS 3.10 so that I can use some of the GRASS components but I keep getting this message:

```
GRASS init error : GRASS was not found in 'F:/QGIS 3.10/apps/grass/grass78' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.
```

I am running Windows 10 with QGIS 3.10.4 with GRASS 7.8.2 and have reinstalled several times, I have gone into `regedit` and removed everything called `qgis`. I am at a loss but really could use the `r.lidar` components.

Comment: AFAIK there are two menu entries to start QGIS: "QGIS" and "QGIS with GRASS GIS" (don't recall the precise wording). So, you need to use "QGIS with GRASS GIS" in order to enable the GRASS GIS support.

Comment: Thanks MarkusN but I have been using QGIS 3.10.4 with GRASS 7.8.2. I will edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Just to be sure of what you have done, markusN was pointing out that after you install QGIS with GRASS, you end up typically with two shortcuts to start QGIS, one will start QGIS just fine but give you an error if you try GRASS, and the second (appropriately called QGIS with GRASS will start QGIS and GRASS will work, but Windows 10 will often (usually?) present you the first shortcut as the most obvious way to start QGIS.

Comment: Hi johns; I do understand that and I have used the second shortcut that you mentioned and this still does not resolve the issue. I found a possible fix on github but after a line by line comparison between the file loaded on my system and the new file that was suggested as a fix, the two files are the same. So I am left with trying to uninstall completely (including a registry edit) and seeing if that will fix the issue. I will update later if that worked. Thanks for your time!